# get 'main' key from multidimensional array using subvalue

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$array = array(
    [45] => [
        account_id => 1
        ],
    [75] => [
        account_id => 2
        ]
)
```

And I have the following PHP-code:

```
$key = array_search(1, array_column($array, 'account_id'));
```

When I do a var_dump($key), the output is int(0). But I need '45' (or '75' in case of account_id 2).

What's the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_combine()` to merge the values and the keys.

```
$array = array(
    45 => [
        'account_id' => 1
        ],
    75 => [
        'account_id' => 2
        ]
);

$key = array_search(1, array_combine( array_keys( $array ), array_column ( $array , 'account_id' ) ) );
```

This will result to: `45`

Comment: Happy to help :) @yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$res=false;$srch=1;
foreach ($array as $key=>$val){
  if ($val['account_id']===$srch) {$res=$key; break;}
}
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and get the first key from the result using [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($x) {
    return $x["account_id"] === 1;
});

echo key($array); //45
```